# Pass nested dictionary location as parameter in Python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

If I have a nested dictionary I can get a key by indexing like so:

```
>>> d = {'a':{'b':'c'}}
>>> d['a']['b']
'c'
```

Am I able to pass that indexing as a function parameter?

```
def get_nested_value(d, path=['a']['b']):
    return d[path]
```

Obviously, this is incorrect, I get `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`.

How can I do it correctly?

Comment: You can however do, `path = ['a','b']` and do `d[path[0]][path[1]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) (or [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) in python 3), but that would also require you to pass in a list/tuple of your keys:

```
>>> def get_nested_value(d, path=('a', 'b')):
        return reduce(dict.get, path, d)

>>> d = {'a': {'b': 'c'}}
>>> get_nested_value(d)
'c'
>>>
```

(In your case `['a']['b']` doesn't work because `['a']` is a list, and `['a']['b']` is trying to look up the element at "*b*"th index of that list)

Comment: Thanks, neat function. I wasn't aware of it before!

Comment: for single depth dicts, you need to pass an empty value e.g: `('a', )`

Answer (score 3):

By rewriting your function body a little bit, you can pass the keys as a tuple or other sequence:

```
def get_nested_value(d, keys):
    for k in keys:
        d = d[k]
    return d

d = {'a':{'b':'c'}}
print get_nested_value(d, ("a", "b"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it with a recursive function:

```
def access_path (lambda json, path): 
    if len(path) == 0:
        return json
    else 
        return access_path(json[path[0]], path[1:]))
```

This works for both a nested dict-of-dicts, and a list of dicts:

```
test = {
    'a' : {
        'b' : 420
    },
    'c' : [
        {
            'id' : 'd1'
        },
        {
            'id' : 'd2'
        },
        {
            'id' : 'd3'
        },
    ]
}

print(access_path(test, ['a', 'b']))
print(access_path(test, ['c', 1, 'id']))
```

prints

```
420
d2
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://github.com/akesterson/dpath-python.

It makes traversing nested dictionaries a lot easier.

It will iterate out all of the conditions in the dictionary, so no special looping constructs required.